# How does estimatedRowHeight affect performance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, autolayout

When use dynamic UITableViewCells height calculation via UITableViewAutomaticDimension you must set estimatedRowHeight. Is there any information about how does bad estimated value affect performance?

Comment: good reading material about performance of `UITableView` and its cells: https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/perfect-smooth-scrolling-in-uitableviews-fd609d5275a5#.qmigr9vhy

Comment: Unfortunately there's only one sentence where UITableViewAutomaticDimension is mentioned.

Comment: you may need to read about how the _constraints_ affect the performance as the dynamic height is generated based on those; I would recommend to read the entire doc altogether, not the headlines only.

Answer (score 3):

Estimated row height is not as important as you necessarily think. It is mainly used by the table to configure certain UI elements like it's scroll bars for instance. When `tableView.reloadData()` is called the table recalculates this anyway. As a general rule I just use an estimated row height of either 44 or whatever the height of my placeholder cell that is displayed whilst I am loading data is. The performance repercussions of using an inaccurate `estimatedRowHeight` are minimal to non-existent as it does not actually contribute to calculating the dynamic height of cells marked as `UITableViewAutomaticDimention`.

Comment: "Estimated row height is not as important as you necessarily think."   I don't agree with this as I've encountered scenarios where defaulting to 44 points was insufficient and actually degraded the performance of rendering my tableview. For example, if the final height of the rendered cell is 200 points, 44 is insufficient especially when your tableview has many cells on it.